# Unable to cast object of type 'System.IO.Ports.SerialStream' to type 'System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream

Tags: c#

I am Getting an Exception saying that Unable to cast object of type '**System.IO.Ports.SerialStream**' to type '**System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream**

when i run below code

please give solution how to overcome this.

```
 private NetworkStream GetStreams_USB_SER()
        {
            sp = new SerialPort();
            NetworkStream Ns ;//= new NetworkStream();

            Stream Is;
            String KEYNAME3 = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\HARDWARE\\DEVICEMAP\\SERIALCOMM";
                string COMPORT = (string)Registry.GetValue(KEYNAME3, "\\Device\\USBSER000", "NOT VALID COM");
                Console.WriteLine("\nOutput3: " + COMPORT);
                sp.PortName = COMPORT;
                sp.BaudRate = 115200;
                //serialport.ReadTimeout = 1000;
                sp.Open();
                if (sp.IsOpen)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Port Detected :");
                    Is = sp.BaseStream;

                    return (NetworkStream)Is;
                }
                else
                {
                    return null;
                }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

C# is a **type-safe** language. That means that you can not assign an expression of a type to a variable of a different type and expect that the types automatically adjust (as opposed to some weakly typed languages like JavaScript). While `NetworkStream` and a `SerialStream` share a common base class (`Stream`), a `NetworkStream` **is not** a `SerialStream` and will never be. So you can not cast one to the other.

The [`SerialPort.BaseStream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.basestream(v=vs.110).aspx) property is of type `Stream`and that's the guarantee this property gives you. You can *try* to cast it into another type (such as `NetworkStream`), but unless the stream actually **is** a `NetworkStream`, this will fail. Alas, the stream returned by the `SerialPort` class is not a network stream and the stream type that it is (`SerialStream`) is not accessible to you, because [it is marked `internal`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system/sys/system/io/ports/SerialStream.cs). So you can not cast it into *any* type that is available to you.

Your only choice in this case is to drop the cast and make your method return a `Stream` instead of a `NetworkStream`:

```
private Stream GetStreams_USB_SER()
```

and

```
return Is;
```

Comment: Actual Problem in Stream is there is no DataAvailable method in it

Comment: You can't choose your types based on the methods you need.  So you have to find another way to go without DataAvailable. Usually you use a StreamReader to read your data. That way you don't need to access low level stream methods.

Answer (score 0):

I created a new class which overrides the NetworkStream Class in that implemented my serial port functions.

```
     public class USB_COMM 
        {
            static private SerialPort SPRT = new SerialPort();
            static String ComPortName = "";
            static int BaudRate = 0;
            public USB_COMM(String sCOMNAME, int iBaudRate)
            {
                ComPortName = sCOMNAME;
                BaudRate = iBaudRate;
                Sckt1 = new Socket(SocketType.Stream,ProtocolType.Tcp);
                Server();
                Sckt1.Connect(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 5000);
                mns= new myStream();
            }
        public NetworkStream NsGetUsbStrm()
        {
            return mns;
        }


            private class myStream : NetworkStream
            {
                public myStream()
                    : base(Sckt1)
                {
                    SPRT.PortName = ComPortName;
                    SPRT.BaudRate = BaudRate;
                }
                public int iOpenPort()
                {
                    try {
                        SPRT.Open();
                        return 0;
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        return 1;
                    }
                }
                public override bool DataAvailable
                {
                    get
                    {
                        int AvilBytes = SPRT.BytesToRead;
                        if (AvilBytes > 0)
                        {
                            return true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                }
                protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
                {
                    base.Dispose(disposing);
                }
                public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int size)
                {

                    if (buffer == null || offset < 0 || size < 0)
                    {
                        throw new ArgumentException();
                    }
                    if (!SPRT.IsOpen)
                        SPRT.Open();
                    return SPRT.Read(buffer, offset, size);
                    //return base.Read(buffer, offset, size);
                }
                public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int size)
                {

                    if (buffer == null || offset < 0 || size < 0)
                    {
                        throw new ArgumentException();
                    }
                    if (!SPRT.IsOpen)
                        SPRT.Open();
                    SPRT.Write(buffer, offset, size);
                    //base.Write(buffer, offset, size);
                }
            }
            private void Server()
            {
                const int PORT_NO = 5000;
                const string SERVER_IP = "127.0.0.1";

                //---listen at the specified IP and port no.---
                IPAddress localAdd = IPAddress.Parse(SERVER_IP);
                TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(localAdd, PORT_NO);
                Console.WriteLine("Listening...");
                listener.Start();

            }

        }
```